# How does eval command work in this example? Related with Apache Maven

Tags: bash, eval

Hello I am a newby and I cannot understand how the `eval` command is working here.
How many args are being evaluated? What does the `\` do here?
Thanks for the help!!!

```
eval "${JAVACMD}" \
 ${MAVEN_OPTS} \
 -classpath "${CLASSWORLDS_JAR}" \
 "-Dclassworlds.conf=${M2_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
 "-Dmaven.home=${M2_HOME}"  \
 "-Dos.arch=`uname -m`" \
 ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} $(${QUIET_FLAG} && echo \-q) $(${OFFLINE_FLAG} && echo \-o) ${QUOTED_ARGS} ${MAVEN_ARGS}
```

Comment: The backslash prevents the interpretation of a character as a special character. On the end of the line, it allows you to type RETURN, and complete the command at the end of a line. Not sure what it's suppose to be doing before the dashes. These aren't interpolated by the shell, so there's no need to _quote_ them.

Answer (score 0):

`About shell bulletin eval:`

> **eval** is useful when command line contains something which needs to be evaluated by the shell. **eval** takes a string as its argument, and evaluates it as if you'd typed that string on a command line.

**PS:** It should be used sparingly and carefully.

`\` is used for line continuation to make string on next line part of same command line.

Answer (score 0):

Good manual for the bash is here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html
It's a very nice and detailed document. All the quotations from my answer are from that manual.

Backslash '\' is an escaping character. It's used for the new line escaping.

> "If a \newline pair appears, and the backslash itself is not quoted, the \newline is treated as a line continuation"

it's also used in your example as a dash escaping:

```
\-q
\-o
```

The backquote '`' is used for the command substitution. It means that for the string

```
uname_m=`uname -m`
```

'uname_m' variable get the return value of the 'uname -m' command
Btw, another variant of command substitution is also used in your code:

> $(...)

It is used in the same way as a backquoted version. So the following commands do the same:

```
uname_m=`uname -m`
uname_m=$(uname -m)
```

'eval' is used to run some external program.

> eval [arguments]
>   The arguments are concatenated together into a single command, which is then read and executed, and its exit status returned as the exit status of eval. If there are no arguments or only empty arguments, the return status is zero.

I don't quite understand why the same command is not just put as it is, without using 'eval', because it's result is not used (due to your code).

btw, you could always look what's happening in the script by printing a trace of all the bash commands.
You could do it externally, just running

```
bash -x script.sh
```

or you could do it modifying the script itself. Just put

```
set -x
```

before any meaningful operations in the script.

Answer (score 0):

It appears `eval` is only being used to conditionally add a pair of arguments to the command line based on the values of `QUIET_FLAG` and `OFFLINE_FLAG`. (Based on the code, it looks like their values are `true` or `false`, so that the command of the same name is executed). A better solution is set the flag to any value to enable it, and leave it unset to disable it.

```
"${JAVACMD}" \
  ${MAVEN_OPTS} \
  -classpath "${CLASSWORLDS_JAR}" \
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=${M2_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
  "-Dmaven.home=${M2_HOME}"  \
  "-Dos.arch=$(uname -m)" \
  ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} ${QUIET_FLAG+:-q} ${OFFLINE_FLAG:+-o} \
  ${QUOTED_ARGS} ${MAVEN_ARGS}
```

If `QUIET_FLAG` is set to any non-empy value, its expansion will be replaced with `-q`; otherwise, the empty string will be substituted, and it will simply vanish from the command line because it isn't quoted. `OFFLINE_FLAG` is handled similarly. This removes the need for `eval` altogether.

To retain the current `true`/`false` settings, use them to set a second set of variables:

```
# variable names are case-sensitive, so these are separate flags
QUIET_FLAG && quiet_flag=-q
OFFLINE_FLAG && offline_flag=-o

"${JAVACMD}" ... ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} $quiet_flag $offline_flag ...
```

---

The above will work in any POSIX shell. If this is for `bash`, you can simplify the command call itself by storing the options in an array. This removes the need for the line continuation character, because the values in an array can be specified on multiple lines; the shell knows the array isn't complete until the closing parentheses is found, whereas a command line is terminated by the first unescaped newline.

```
java_opts=( ${MAVEN_OPTS}
            -classpath "${CLASSWORLDS_JAR}"
            "-Dclassworlds.conf=${M2_HOME}/bin/m2.conf"
            "-Dmaven.home=${M2_HOME}" 
            "-Dos.arch=$(uname -m)"
            ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER}
            ${QUIET_FLAG+:-q}
            ${OFFLINE_FLAG:+-o}
            ${QUOTED_ARGS}
            ${MAVEN_ARGS}
)

"${JAVACMD}" "${java_opts[@]}"
```